# Using a boolean array with all values initialized to true and turn them to false until one is left

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I have a random number set to x and a Boolean array that is initialized to true. I need to be able to start at the random number (x) and turn every third value to false until there is one true value left. The true value is the new "winner." This is what I have so far any suggestions would be great.

```
int win;
for( win = x; win < trueStatus.length; win++)
    {
        if((win % 3 == 0 && trueStatus[win]==true))
        {
            trueStatus[win]=false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your specific problem with this code?

Comment: when I print out who wins its the same as the random number and it shouldn't be.

Comment: You need to elaborate on "until there is one true value left"

Comment: I think we need more context here. Provide more context, more code to replicate your problem and we will help you on how to solve it

Comment: And what should happen, if you will go to end of array? (for example array of 6 elements[indexes from [0 to 5] you started at index 3, then what should next element, that should be false - 0? Also, what in situation, when size of array is dividing by 3? (in this case even if there will loop in array [so after index 5 you are going to index 0] you will be still going on the same indexes and never will be situation, that just one number will left

Comment: if there was 11 numbers in my text file then you will have         1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 all set to true. If the random number is 3 then 6, 9, 1, 4, 8, 2, 7, 3, 11, and 5 will be eliminated and 10 would win.

Comment: My program has a txt file full of 100 strings. I have already put the strings in one array so I can print out the winning string. The I got a random number (x) to know where to start. Then I made my Boolean array with 100 values set to true to simulate what is in the other array. Then I will need to start at the random number and set every third position to false but the problem I have is that I don't know how to make the array start at the first position once it reaches the end and also how to print out the "winning" string.

Answer (score 0):

First, your criteria for `win` (last one still `true`) requires that you get a new random number each time.... basically, you need something to count the number of `true`(s) in your `boolean[]`. Using a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) that might look like

```
private static int countTrues(boolean[] arr) {
    int c = 0;
    for (boolean b : arr) {
        if (b) {
            c++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Then you can loop until there is a *winner* like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    boolean[] trueStatus = new boolean[10];
    Arrays.fill(trueStatus, true);
    Random rand = new Random();
    while (countTrues(trueStatus) > 1) {
        trueStatus[rand.nextInt(trueStatus.length)] = false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < trueStatus.length; i++) {
        if (trueStatus[i]) {
            System.out.println("winner at " + i);
            break;
        }
    }
    // Display entire array to prove there is only one "true"
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(trueStatus));
}
```

Also, if you want to iterate by multiples of three please use `+= 3` (it's *much* faster then incrementing by one and testing with modulo 3).

Answer (score 0):

My proposition of solution:

```
private static int findWinner(boolean[] trueStatus, int x) {
    int win = 0;
    if (trueStatus == null || trueStatus.length % 3 == 0 || x < 0 || x >= trueStatus.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    int numberOfTrues = trueStatus.length;

    if (trueStatus.length == 1) {
        return 0;
    }


    if (trueStatus.length == 2) {
        return 1 - x;
    }

    int index = x;
    while (numberOfTrues > 1) {
        if (trueStatus[index]) {
            trueStatus[index] = false;
            numberOfTrues--;
            index = (index + 3) % trueStatus.length;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < trueStatus.length; i++) {
        if (trueStatus[i]) {
            win = i;
            break;
        }
    }


    return win;
}
```

**EDIT:** There is also smarter way of finding formula, and in this case should be:

```
win = (trueStatus.length - 3 + x) % trueStatus.length;
```

And full method will be:

```
private static int findWinner(boolean[] trueStatus, int x) {
    int win = 0;
    if (trueStatus == null || trueStatus.length % 3 == 0 || x < 0 || x >= trueStatus.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    int numberOfTrues = trueStatus.length;

    if (trueStatus.length == 1) {
        return 0;
    }


    if (trueStatus.length == 2) {
        return 1 - x;
    }

    win = (trueStatus.length - 3 + x) % trueStatus.length;

    return win;
}
```